# How can i disable the upload validation on submit ?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, file-io

I am using the bootstrap fileinput from [here](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input/demo)

This is the html part:

```
    <input id="file-0"  type="file" multiple data-min-file-count="1" name = "avatar" >
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

and this is the js part:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#file-0").fileinput({
            allowedFileExtensions : ['jpg', 'png','gif'],
            showUpload:false,
            showCancel:false,
            showRemove: false,

    });
});
```

When I press the submit button this message appears

```
"You must select at least 1 file to upload. Please retry your upload!"
```

How can I remove it?  I did not submit my form if I did not upload a file.

Comment: Which plugin are you using for file upload?

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
multiple data-min-file-count="1"
```

To this:

```
multiple data-min-file-count="0"
```